# Android - add fragment with custom dimensions

Tags: android, android-fragments

Currently, I am adding a fragment using the following code.

```
private void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String fragmentName) {
    Log.i("Adder", "Adding fragment " + fragmentName);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragmentName);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Following code is for resizing the added fragment.

```
private boolean readjustFragment(Fragment fragmentToBeAdjusted, FragmentCoordinates fragmentCoordinates) {
    if (fragmentToBeAdjusted != null) {
        View view = fragmentToBeAdjusted.getView();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(fragmentCoordinates.getWidth(), fragmentCoordinates.getHeight());
        params.leftMargin = fragmentCoordinates.getX0();
        params.bottomMargin = fragmentCoordinates.getY0();
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        view.requestLayout();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But instead of adding and then resizing, how do I add a fragment with custom dimensions (height, width and margins) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can pass desired width height and margin to fragment and assign that value while inflating the view**

For example if you are using Frame layout as container for fragments then pass values with new instance method

```
/**
         * 
         * @param widthInDP
         * @param heightinDP
         * @param leftMarginDp
         * @param topMarginDp
         * @param rightMarginDp
         * @param bottomMarginDp
         * @param fragIndex
         * @return
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int widthInDP,
                int heightinDP, int leftMarginDp, int topMarginDp,
                int rightMarginDp, int bottomMarginDp, int fragIndex) {
            PlaceholderFragment resizableFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();

            // Test purpose Only
            args.putInt(INDEX, fragIndex);

            // Set Width Height dynamically
            args.putInt(WIDTH, widthInDP);
            args.putInt(HEIGHT, heightinDP);

            // SetMargin
            args.putInt(LEFT_MARGIN, leftMarginDp);
            args.putInt(RIGHT_MARGIN, rightMarginDp);
            args.putInt(TOP_MARGIN, topMarginDp);
            args.putInt(BOTTOM_MARGIN, bottomMarginDp);
            resizableFragment.setArguments(args);

            return resizableFragment;
        }
```

And then apply them in `onCreateView` method. Point to note here if you are using Frame layout as container for fragments then use `FrameLayout` param else you will get exception.

```
   FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) rootView
            .getLayoutParams();

    // set width height
    params.height = dpToPx(getArguments().getInt(HEIGHT));
    params.width = dpToPx(getArguments().getInt(WIDTH));

    // substitute
    // parameters for left,top, right, bottom
    params.setMargins(dpToPx(getArguments().getInt(LEFT_MARGIN)),
            dpToPx(getArguments().getInt(TOP_MARGIN)),
            dpToPx(getArguments().getInt(RIGHT_MARGIN)),
            dpToPx(getArguments().getInt(BOTTOM_MARGIN)));
    rootView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

**Output :-**

Orange background is my `Frame layout` container and all other are resized `Fragments` with custom margins in same container. You can also play around with `LayoutParam.Gravity` property to make them go left right, top, bottom , center, bottom- center, top center and so on

[image]

**Complete code I used in sample**

```
package com.example.fragment;

    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container,
                                PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(400, 400, 50, 50,
                                        50, 50, 1)).commit();

                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container,
                                PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(300, 300, 30, 30,
                                        30, 30, 2)).commit();

                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container,
                                PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(200, 200, 20, 20,
                                        20, 20, 3)).commit();

                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container,
                                PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(100, 100, 10, 10,
                                        10, 10, 4)).commit();
            }
        }

        /**
         * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
         */
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

            private static final String HEIGHT = "Height";
            private static final String WIDTH = "Width";
            private static final String LEFT_MARGIN = "left";
            private static final String RIGHT_MARGIN = "right";
            private static final String TOP_MARGIN = "top";
            private static final String BOTTOM_MARGIN = "bottom";

            // Test Data
            private static final String INDEX = "FragNumber";

            /**
             * 
             * @param widthInDP
             * @param heightinDP
             * @param leftMarginDp
             * @param topMarginDp
             * @param rightMarginDp
             * @param bottomMarginDp
             * @param fragIndex
             * @return
             */
            public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int widthInDP,
                    int heightinDP, int leftMarginDp, int topMarginDp,
                    int rightMarginDp, int bottomMarginDp, int fragIndex) {
                PlaceholderFragment resizableFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();

                Bundle args = new Bundle();

                // Test purpose Only
                args.putInt(INDEX, fragIndex);

                // Set Width Height dynamically
                args.putInt(WIDTH, widthInDP);
                args.putInt(HEIGHT, heightinDP);

                // SetMargin
                args.putInt(LEFT_MARGIN, leftMarginDp);
                args.putInt(RIGHT_MARGIN, rightMarginDp);
                args.putInt(TOP_MARGIN, topMarginDp);
                args.putInt(BOTTOM_MARGIN, bottomMarginDp);
                resizableFragment.setArguments(args);

                return resizableFragment;
            }

            public PlaceholderFragment() {
            }

            public int dpToPx(int dp) {
                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getActivity().getResources()
                        .getDisplayMetrics();
                int px = Math.round(dp
                        * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
                return px;
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                        false);

                FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) rootView
                        .getLayoutParams();

                // set width height
                params.height = dpToPx(getArguments().getInt(HEIGHT));
                params.width = dpToPx(getArguments().getInt(WIDTH));

                // substitute
                // parameters for left,top, right, bottom
                params.setMargins(dpToPx(getArguments().getInt(LEFT_MARGIN)),
                        dpToPx(getArguments().getInt(TOP_MARGIN)),
                        dpToPx(getArguments().getInt(RIGHT_MARGIN)),
                        dpToPx(getArguments().getInt(BOTTOM_MARGIN)));
                rootView.setLayoutParams(params);

                // Test purpose Only
                switch (getArguments().getInt(INDEX)) {
                case 1:
                    rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);

                    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.frag_index))
                            .setText("Fragment # " + getArguments().getInt(INDEX));

                    break;

                case 2:
                    rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.frag_index))
                            .setText("Fragment # " + getArguments().getInt(INDEX));

                    break;

                case 3:
                    rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.frag_index))
                            .setText("Fragment # " + getArguments().getInt(INDEX));

                    break;

                default:
                    rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.frag_index))
                            .setText("Fragment # " + getArguments().getInt(INDEX));

                    break;
                }

                return rootView;
            }
        }
    }
```

So technically this is doable but I didn't understand why you are trying to do this way ?

Comment: I've just printed this solution =) Don't forget, LayoutParams should have type of your container.

Comment: Yes it's good solution. But I used builder instead of newInstance.

Comment: width, height, leftMargin and topMargin would suffice right ? Added to these if we take in rightMargin and bottomMargin - it either results in inconsistency or redundancy. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: //Yes and No,  it will totally depend upon use case 

((leftMargin == rightMargin )&&(topMargin ==bottom]Margin))? ( Yes leftMargin and topMargin is suffice) : (No pass all margins);

Comment: leftMargin + width + rightMargin = screenWidth (Here, screen width can be extracted at runtime). Then why do we need all of leftMargin, width and rightMargin ? In any case only 2 of these 3 would be sufficient, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by specifying LayoutParams in fragment's onCreateView, like this -

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.so_demo_frag,container,false);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 400);
    v.setLayoutParams(p);
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Just add it with framelayout in your mainActvity and add your fragment like this: 

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/playfragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />


 FragmentPlay frg2 = new FragmentPlay();//create the fragment instance for the top fragment
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();//create an instance of Fragment-transaction
        transaction.add(R.id.playfragment, frg2, "Frag_Top_tag");
        transaction.commit();
```

Comment: I have done exactly the same for adding a new fragment, but I needed a way to set the dimensions of the fragment dynamically. Hitesh's solution was a really nice way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to try making your own ViewGroup? It is ViewGroup responsibility to adjust childs position in onLayout() and its sizes in onMeasure(). Just extend needed viewgroup and override methods with the logic and constraints your want.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the dimensions on the container view, `R.id.fragment_container` in your case, and let the fragment take up all the available space.

Comment: I need the container to be able to contain multiple fragments. When fragment resize is possible, why can't I set the size during add time itself ?